# sqlloader and manage nulls

Tags: plsql, sql-loader

I need to manage nulls in my sqlloader.

The example:

my data:

```
2;200A;
1;300B;45
5;105C;
6;204D;;
```

My ctl file:

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE *
insert INTO TABLE TABLE_AUX
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
(
   CODE1,
   CODE2,
   CODE3
)
```

And the result in my table:

```
2    200A 

1    300B    45

5    105C  

6    204D    (null)
```

I need the blanks are nulls.
I know if in my data put another ";" at the end the problem will be solved but I can´t touch this file.

Thank you!

Comment: In oracle blank ''  and null are same. Which database you are using?pleaee check query select * from table_aux where code3 is null.

Comment: Sorry, but when i do that:
select count(CODE3) from TABLE_AUXL; Result -> 3

Comment: What is the output you are getting from query?

Comment: Can you please check output of my query in 1st comment? And share the output

Comment: Sorry. The output of your query is 0

Comment: Record 1: Rejected - Error on table "TABLE_AUX", column CODE3.
Column not found before end of logical record (use TRAILING NULLCOLS)
Record 3: Rejected - Error on table "TABLE_AUX", column CODE3.
Column not found before end of logical record (use TRAILING NULLCOLS)

Comment: getting above error in sqlloader log, how you loaded the other two records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below query

```
select * from table_aux where trim(code3) is null;


select * from table_aux where code3 is null;

select * from table_aux where code3=' ';
```

there must be some spaces in code3 column of record 2 and 5.

So convert space into null use below code

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE *
insert INTO TABLE TABLE_AUX
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
(
   CODE1,
   CODE2,
   CODE3  trim(:CODE3)
)
```